# I want to download a 1.2 GB file, but the transfer always fails at 1.08 GB. Is it possible to download the file in two pieces?

Tags: download, nginx, wget, curl

I can download 1.08 GB of the file without any difficulty, but the download invariably fails at that point. I am fairly sure this is because nginx writes temp files to disk before sending them to the client, and the host's nginx proxy buffer is limited to 1.08 GB.

I have not been able to continue the downloads, ever. The temp file is automatically deleted and the download attempt automatically restarts from zero at failure, only to inevitably fail again.

I have tried curl, wget, a variety of browsers, JDownloader, and lftp. No luck with any of the above.

Is there a way to download most of the file beginning-to-end, and then request it again, only starting from the end and working toward the beginning, ultimately ending up with two pieces that can be combined to recreate the file?

(The host knows about the configuration issue. They are a very bureaucratic organization and are taking forever to fix it.)

Comment: aria2? (with `-c`)

Comment: No dice, unfortunately. "errorCode=8 Invalid range header." When I restart the transfer, aria2 attempts to resume, but ultimately throws the same error. Very cool piece of software, though. Thank you for the introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to split transfers in HTTP is using the `Range` header.

Error 8 "Invalid range header" means that the server sent a reply that curl could not understand (https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html :

> CURLE_WEIRD_SERVER_REPLY (8)
>
> The server sent data libcurl could not parse.

So it could be the server does not support the range header, and you are out of luck.

"Invalid range header" also could mean that your given range is invalid (e.g. too large), and that you could fix that yourself by passing a valid range.